# T-SQL Use Table Variable or Sum Against Parent Table

Tags: performance, t-sql

The scenario is this, I am creating a log table that will end up being quite large once it is all said and done and I want to create a status table that will query from the table with different date ranges and sum the results into multiple total fields.

I plan on writing this into a Stored Procedure but my question would I gain the best performance from reading all my records from the log table into a temp table before doing the sum operations.

IE I have this table:

```
SummaryValues
90DayValues 
60DayValues
30DayValues
14DayValues
7DayValues
1DayValues
```

Would it be logical to make a take all values for the previous 90 days and then insert them into a table value before then calculating my sum for my 6 fields in my summary table or would it be just as fast to execute 6 sum statements from the log table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you are better reading into a temp table first. Sometimes not. This makes sense if you have multiple passes of processing on the same data

However, if you want "last 90 days", "last 60 day" etc then it can be done in one query

Reading the question again, I'd just run one query and calculate all values in one go. And not bother with any intermediate tables

```
SELECT
  Stuff, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN dayDiff <= 90 THEN SomeValue ELSE 0 END) AS SumValue90, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN dayDiff <= 60 THEN SomeValue ELSE 0 END) AS SumValue60, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN dayDiff <= 30 THEN SomeValue ELSE 0 END) AS SumValue30
FROM
   (
    SELECT
      Stuff, 
      DATEDIFF(day, SomeData, GETDATE()) AS dayDiff
    FROM
      Mytable
    WHERE
       ...
    ) foo
GROUP BY
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a more straight forward way of solving that problem but it wasn't coming to me off hand.